# How to pass variables between screens(classes) in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a program which lets me use wolframalpha and wikipedia search engines and whatever else I want among other things. My issue is that I cannot seem to pass my answer variable into the answer screen from the question screen.

There are already posts on the site about this, however I have looked extensively at all them and none of them seemed to fix my issue, it simply produced a different error. If anyone could help explain to me what is wrong it would be much appreciated

I've tried so many different things I don't know if I'm overlooking a simple mistake or not.

```
Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
    QIPA:
        id:main
        name: "mainprogramme"
    QIPA_output:
        id:output
        name: "answer_screen"

<QIPA>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size: root.size
            spacing: 20
            padding: 20
            Label:
                text: "Hello, I am QIPA, your virtual assistant. How may I be of service?"
                font_size: "25sp"
            TextInput:
                id:question
                multiline: False
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "back"
                font_size: "25sp"



<QIPA_output>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 20
        padding: 20
        Label:
            id: output
            text: root.answer
            font_size: "10sp"
        Button:
            text: "back"
            size_hint: 1,.3
            font_size: "25sp"
            on_press:root.BacktoMainProgramme()
""")

class QIPA(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(QIPA, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
            self.OnEnter()

    def OnEnter(self):
        input = self.ids.question.text
        input = input.lower()


        try:
            #wolframalpha
            app_id = "G6YEVU-LJTJ5ETLHV"
            client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

            res = client.query(input)
            answer = (next(res.results).text)
            self.manager.current = "answer_screen"

            print answer
        except:
            #wikipedia
            wikipedia.set_lang("en")
            answer = wikipedia.summary(input, sentences=3)
            self.manager.current = "answer_screen"

            global answer



class QIPA_output(Screen):
    answer = StringProperty()
    answer = QIPA.OnEnter.answer
    def BacktoMainProgramme(self):
        self.manager.current = "mainprogramme"
```

This is a simplified version of my code, the errors I receive are either

```
AttributeError: 'QIPA_output' object has no attribute 'answer' or <bound method QIPA_output.answer of <Screen name=">> or  Traceback (most recent call last)
```

depending on what I've tried to do with my code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get values from a different screen (kivy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687793/get-values-from-a-different-screen-kivy)

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the class attribute, `answer` declared in `class QIPA_output()` from `class QIPA()`, use the `ids` that were added in kv file.

## Method OnEnter()

- Replace `answer` with `self.manager.ids.output.answer`
- Remove `global answer`

## Class QIPA_output

- Remove `answer = QIPA.OnEnter.answer`

## Snippets

```
    def OnEnter(self):
        input = self.ids.question.text
        input = input.lower()

        try:
            # wolframalpha
            app_id = "G6YEVU-LJTJ5ETLHV"
            client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

            res = client.query(input)
            self.manager.ids.output.answer = (next(res.results).text)

            print(f'answer={self.manager.ids.output.answer}')
        except:
            # wikipedia
            wikipedia.set_lang("en")
            self.manager.ids.output.answer = wikipedia.summary(input, sentences=3)
        self.manager.current = "answer_screen"


class QIPA_output(Screen):
    answer = StringProperty('')

    def BacktoMainProgramme(self):
        self.manager.current = "mainprogramme"
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you ever so much, I really appreciate your detailed explanation. I would upvote if I could but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation

Comment: ***"If you want to say "thank you," accept that person's answer."*** [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)