# How can i get the text of an MDTextField (Or Data "Login") of an screen if im in another Screen. (Kivy / KivyMD / Python)

Tags: python, oop, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

im new using classes and kivy/kivyMD, I have a trouble and it is that i want to get the text of an MDTextFied (Or Data "Login" of my Query) who belongs to the AScreen if im working from the class definition of the BScreen?

My minimal code is like, **ScreenManager File**:

```
 <AScreen>:
    name:'ascreen'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
    MDTextField:
        id: user
        hint_text: 'User'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Login'
        on_release: root.login_button()

<BScreen>:
    name:'bscreen'     
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Registrar Equipo'
        on_release: root.show_login_data()
```

The **class file of my screens** is:

```
class AScreen(Screen):
    def login_button(self):
    ...
    login = #User DB info
    """Here i do a query to the DB with the text of my MDTextField on AScreen
    i use self.ids.user.text to get the text of the AScreen MDTextField
    if the user exist in the DB i save the user's data on a variable named "login" """
    
class BScreen(Screen):
    def show_login_data(self):
        print()
```

For now I'm just trying to print the text from AScreen.ids.user.text or also get the login variable but I haven't got either of those.

My **main file** is:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(screensfile.AScreen(name='ascreen'))
sm.add_widget(screensfile.BScreen(name='bscreen'))

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return self.screen
MainApp().run()
```

I have tried the following (**I apologize for my horrible rookie mistakes**):
print(AScreen.login_button().login)
print(Acreen.ids.user.text)

I know there are a similar cases here, but it doesn't help me for my screens.py file:
[Kivy - Use text from TextInput of one screen in another screen in .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60960386/kivy-use-text-from-textinput-of-one-screen-in-another-screen-in-py-file)

[get values from a different screen (kivy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687793/get-values-from-a-different-screen-kivy)

I know that the most probable thing is that I have a bad interpretation of the work with the classes, but with the way that the screens work in kivy (screens look for the definition of a class of the same name) I would not know how to do it.
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `screen_helper` defines a `ScreenManager` as the Apps root widget with `AScreen` and `BScreen` as its children. In that case you can reference the `MDTextField` in `AScreen` as:

```
App.get_running_app().root.get_screen('ascreen').ids.user
```

The `App.get_running_app()` returns the instance of the running `App`. The `root` references the root widget (which I am assuming is a `ScreenManager`). The `get_screen()` method of the `ScreenManager` returns the instance of `AScreen`, and the `ids.user` gets a reference to the `MDTextField`.
Trying to access the ids using the class `AScreen` will not work as the ids are defined in the instance of `AScreen`.

On an unrelated note, if your `build()` method returns the results of `Builder.load_string`, then the lines:

```
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(screensfile.AScreen(name='ascreen'))
sm.add_widget(screensfile.BScreen(name='bscreen'))
```

are building an unused `sm`, and can be removed.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and give an answer, which helped me a lot with my code since it has been a great solution, I still do not know many useful methods even though I always try to go and look at the documentation. I wasn't really sure if what I was doing was redundant or not since in the ScreenManagerFile I do this:

screen_helper = "" "
ScreenManager:
AScreen:
BScreen:

Now I understand that they are two different ways of doing the same thing.
Thank you!